# Django why function can't be stopped with redirect to a specific URL

Tags: django, redirect, httpresponse, reverse

In a function (**create_mapping**) I call another function (**GetCsvHeadersAndSamples**) that calls another function (**get_csv**) that tries to get a CSV file. I want to check in this last function if the file is present before displaying a form or return a request message saying the file was not found.

I also use the **get_csv** function in a bunch of other places

**create_mapping()**

```
def create_mapping(request, pk):
    flow = Flow.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if flow.fl_file_name == "":
        messages.error(
            request, 'Aucun fichier n\'a été enregistré pour ce flux. Veuillez le télécharger et mettre à jour le flux.')
        return redirect('flows:flow-update', pk=pk)
    fl_fiche_header_flow = fetch_fiche_headers(pk)
    headers_samples = GetCsvHeadersAndSamples(request, pk) # <------ call #2 func. HERE
    headers_json = make_headers_json(headers_samples['headers'])
    form = MappingForm(request.POST or None,
                       headers_samples=headers_samples, fl_fiche_header_flow=fl_fiche_header_flow)
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'flow': flow,
        # 'mappings': mappings,
        'headers_json': headers_json,
        'title': 'Création Mapping Field',
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
[...]
```

**GetCsvHeadersAndSamples()**

```
def GetCsvHeadersAndSamples(request, flow_id):
    # returns tuple (file, separator, encoding)
    get_file_and_attribs = get_csv(request, flow_id).  # <------ call #3 func. HERE
    file = get_file_and_attribs[0]
    separator = get_file_and_attribs[1]
    encoding = get_file_and_attribs[2]
    with open(file, newline='', encoding=encoding) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=separator)
        headers = next(reader)
        samples = next(itertools.islice(csv.reader(f), 1, None))
    headersAndSamples = {'headers': headers, 'samples': samples}
    return headersAndSamples
```

**get_csv()**

```
def get_csv(request, flow_id):
    flow = Flow.objects.get(pk=flow_id)
    file = flow.fl_file_name
    separator = flow.fl_separator
    media_folder = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    file = os.path.join(media_folder, str(file))
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        file_2_test = urllib.request.urlopen('file://' + file).read()
        encoding = (chardet.detect(file_2_test))['encoding']
        return (file, separator, encoding)
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Fichier introuvable ou corrompu.")
        # return reverse_lazy('flows:mappings-list', args=(flow_id,))
        # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('flows:mappings-list', args=(flow_id,)))
        # return redirect(f'/flows/flow/{flow_id}')
        # return redirect('flows:mappings-list', pk=flow_id)
```

The 4 commented lines above are all I tried to do. Whatever the option I choose, **GetCsvHeadersAndSamples()** continues its execution. I would like to abort and redirect as soon as **get_csv()** doesn't find the file.

Why doesn't redirection works ?